# apt --fix-broken install does not fix dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I am trying to install `sdrangel`. dpkg tells me that there are unmet dependencies. I tried `sudo apt install -f`. It removed the package I was trying to install and exited without error message

```
markos@elitebook:~/Downloads/sdrangel-1550-master$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  sdrangel
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 74,9 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 269227 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing sdrangel (7.4.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
```

This keeps happening and I can't find a solution online. How can I fix this.

Comment: https://snapcraft.io/install/sdrangel/ubuntu

Comment: I installed the snap and it didn't open. Other people had the same issue too.

Answer (score 2):

`apt --fix-broken` is doing what's supposed to do in this case. It removes a package that can't be installed in your system as it has dependencies that are not available for install.

Although it is not directly supported by SDrangel [developers](https://github.com/f4exb/sdrangel/wiki/Quick-start), you could try to install SDrangel via snap, as explained [here](https://snapcraft.io/install/sdrangel/ubuntu).